# 17.10 ldap - client cannot connect to server and stays in boot loop

Tags: boot, networking, ldap, systemd-logind

How to fix a LDAP client installation in Ubuntu 17.10, which was working fine in Ubuntu 16.04?

With the following configuration Ubuntu 17.10 will hang in a boot loop, so you will not even have a chance to log in.

Installation of LDAP - Client user - management identical in 16.04 & 17.10:

packages:

```
apt-get install ldap-auth-client nscd libpam-cracklib
```

configuration of pam-stack with:

```
auth-client-config -t nss -p lac_ldap
```

and parameters changed in `/etc/ldap.conf`

```
host ldap01 ldap02
base dc=example,dc=com
binddn cn=ldapread,dc=example,dc=com
bindpw xxxxxxxx
```

Comment: Thanks, for feedback. First I wanted to keep the question short, to post the answer direct after. I hope the question is now better understandable, with out unrolling a complete ldap-user-configuration in the pam stack.

Answer (score 1):

### Partial solution

In `/etc/ldap.conf`:

`host ldap01 ldap02` (was working in 16.04)

has to be replaced with:

```
host 10.0.0.9 10.0.0.10
```

otherwise the system stays in an endless loop at the boot process

Without a network-cable the system still stays in an endless loop at the boot process.

### Complete solution

In `/etc/ldap.conf`:

default Reconnect policy:

```
bind_policy hard
```

has to be changed to:

```
bind_policy soft
```

then:

In `/etc/ldap.conf`: -> `host ldap01 ldap02` works as expected, and PC boots normally even without a network-cable.

Answer (score 0):

Use `libpam-ldapd` and `libnss-ldapd` instead of `libpam-cracklib`.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to edit  your question  to expand it with specific details about what you do